# Mutable list of data in Kotlin

Tags: android, list, firebase, kotlin, stringbuilder

Please how can I perform addition  function  with a mutable list of type Double in kotlin?
I have a mutable list of numbers I get
from Firebase
How can I write a function to Find the mathematical  sum of the numbers in the list (Kotlin)?

Comment: what have you tried ? what isn't working ? please add your code as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can reduce function to calculate the sum

```
val list = mutablelistOf(1,2,3,4)

val sum = list.reduce{ a,b ->
 return a + b
}
```

Comment: Or you can just call `.sum()` on the list.